# Unable to Open .DBF Files in Windows 7 That Had Worked Under XP

Tags: .net, vb.net, dbf, oledbconnection

I have a VB.NET application that will let me preview .DBF files that come in from some of our clients. The application then attempts to spit out a CSV from this file that we can then use in our various environments.
This application worked under Windows XP 32 bit. Our company recently upgraded most of us to Windows 7 x64 which has caused this application to fail. I verified that the target build for this application is x86 and not "any CPU" and rebuilt the app but same issues occur.

It originally used `System.Data.Odbc` and `connection.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft dBASE VFP Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType = DBF;SourceDB=" & dbfSourcePath & ";Exclusive=No; Collate=Machine;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;"`.
The location of the failure is at `connection.Open()`. The error given is: "ERROR [IM001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function".

I noticed that the drivers for VFP were not installed and that the Access DBF drivers did not work similar to the post [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/0736e2fd-d70b-4bd6-be12-234e227a5370). The fix listed there is to install VFPro SP2, however, we do not have any FoxPro installs to install a service pack on top of. I then tried to install the OLEDB driver for VFP 9.0 and am now using `System.Data.OleDb` and `connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;SourceDB=" & dbfSourcePath & ";"` but it now tells me that the `connection.Open()` line has this error: "Feature is not available".

I am at a complete loss as to how to get this application to work under Windows 7 x64.
Below are the 2 variants of the code with the file open path removed for readability (I have verified the path and file exist):

ODBC version:

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "SELECT * FROM " & dbfSourceName
Dim connection As New Odbc.OdbcConnection
Dim adp As New Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
connection.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft dBASE VFP Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType = DBF;SourceDB=" & dbfSourcePath & ";Exclusive=No; Collate=Machine;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;"
Dim command As New OdbcCommand(strSelect, connection)
connection.Open()          ' Here is where it throws the error.
```

OLEDB version:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "SELECT * FROM " & dbfSourceName
Dim connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection()
Dim adp As New Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;SourceDB=" & dbfSourcePath & ";"
Dim Command As New OleDbCommand(strSelect, connection)
connection.Open()          'Error occurs here.
```

How can I use either an OLEDB or ODBC connection to open these .DBF files under Windows 7 x64?

Comment: Check this: http://connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro

Comment: Yep, went to that site before I posted here. The problem is that the connection.Open() fails under Windows 7 x64. The ODBC version worked correctly under Windows XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried a few alternate connection strings? Take a look at [www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro](http://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro)

```
connection.ConnectionString = _
  "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
  dbfSourcePath & ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;"
```

Also see the note on using Jet for Access on [64 bit systems](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments)

**Update:**
As an alternative to using the Jet driver, you can access the DBF directly, fortunately the file format is relatively simple. Here is an existing Code Project solution that demonstrates this direct access.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/bugs/LoadDBF.aspx

Comment: I have tried various connection string parameters and have yet to find one that works. I have looked at all of the variants on that Connection Strings page and still no joy. I have been getting different errors: ISAM, Table not in expected format, "Nothing to do". If I knew what type of DBF type these are it would be much easier. Also Access 2010 cannot open these files so that is no help.

Comment: @wergeld, what type of processing do you do with the DBF? If you simply read all the data and are not concerned with the index files, the DBF format is quite simple. You could easily write some code to read the DBF directly. http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm

Comment: The data is read in and some transforms/filtering is done on the fields before being spat out as a flat text file. Indexes, Keys, etc are not used (from the .DBF file, they are used in the destination of course). The issue has to do with a change in the way the drivers are working (or not working). The link provided for using JET on 64-bit did not address the issue I am facing. The link to the DBF v7 file doc is interesting but creating a DBF reader from scratch is not on my horizon as of now =).

Comment: @wergeld, well at code project there is a ready made class that you could use, at least as a starting point. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/bugs/LoadDBF.aspx

Comment: Chris, that code project link worked great! If you want you can update your answer and I will mark it as the correct one.